# Is there a way of requesting data through socket? GRAPHQL + REACT

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am finding a way to send/receive data through socket. for example chat app send data through socket and vice-versa not via http.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a chat application using graphql subscription they are easy to implement 
 and uses inbuilt socket for it.

Here's reference link for grapgql subscription:- https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/7-subscriptions